# Highlight specific days in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to highlight some days in my time series ggplot. But I don't know how to highlight all.

I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

highlight_max <- canteen_menu_data %>%  
filter(date == c("2016-10-04","2017-09-27"))

highlight_min <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date == c("2016-12-27","2017-07-28"))

highlight_christmas2016 <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date == c("2016-12-21","2016-12-30"))

highlight_christmas2017 <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date == c("2017-12-18","2017-12-21"))

dput(canteen_menu_data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=sales)) + 
  geom_line(alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_max, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='red',size=3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_min, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='red',size=3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_christmas2016, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='darkred',size=1) +  
  geom_point(data=highlight_christmas2017, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='darkred',size=1)
```

When I run this, all the point are highlighted in my plot but the last line  doesn't do anything as you can see in the picture

[Daily sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZFxg.png)

Can you please help me?

Comment: hi, your code is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) because we don't have access to your data (```canteen_menu_data```). You can add a sample of your data in your post with ```dput()``` or use a dataset included in base R, like ```mtcars``` or ```iris``` (these are not useful for time series but surely there are some datasets for this that are available for everybody)

Comment: can you reproduce it now?

Comment: Perhaps those dates don't exist in your data.

Comment: @AndrewGustar the dates exist

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 2):

I think you made an error in the filtering, if you have two or more conditions, you should use %in% or specify with "|", for example,

```
highlight_max <- canteen_menu_data %>%  
filter(date == c("2016-10-04","2017-09-27"))
```

Should be:

```
filter(date %in% c("2016-10-04","2017-09-27"))
```

or:

```
filter(date == "2016-10-04"| date == "2017-09-27")
```

Also I am not sure if your `date` column is a `character` or `Date`. Please check using `str(canteen_menu_date)`. We can simulate some data below, and I set the date column as should be able to reproduce the correct points:

```
set.seed(999)
canteen_menu_data = data.frame(
date = seq(as.Date("2016-10-01"),as.Date("2017-12-31"),by="day"),
sales = runif(457,min=100,max=400)
)

highlight_max <- canteen_menu_data %>%  
filter(date %in% as.Date(c("2016-10-04","2017-09-27")))

highlight_min <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date %in% as.Date(c("2016-12-27","2017-07-28")))

highlight_christmas2016 <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date %in% as.Date(c("2016-12-21","2016-12-30")))

highlight_christmas2017 <- canteen_menu_data %>% 
filter(date %in% as.Date(c("2017-12-18","2017-12-21")))

canteen_menu_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=sales)) + 
  geom_line(alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_max, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='red',size=3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_min, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='red',size=3) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_christmas2016, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='darkred',size=1) +  
  geom_point(data=highlight_christmas2017, aes(x=date,y=sales), color='darkred',size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Just one more question @StupidWolf. How can I label the point in the graph?

Comment: To the code above, you add something like + geom_label(data=highlight_max, aes(x=date,y=sales,label="highlight_max"),
  nudge_x=20,nudge_y=20,label.size =0.1). So you need to play with the nudge_x and nudge_y to get a good visualization. Otherwise I suggest looking at the package ggrepel, with  geom_text_repel